# Access VBA: Resetting a Date on a Form

Tags: vba, date, ms-access, controls

I'm trying to create a button with VBA code (on click) to empty a form in order for a new entry to be started, or an entry to be restarted. The below code works...

```
Public Sub clearForms()
Dim frm As Form
Set frm = Forms!Person_Name

Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In frm.Controls
    With ctl
        Select Case .ControlType
            Case acTextBox
                .Value = " "
            Case acCheckBox
                .Value = False
            Case acComboBox
                .SetFocus
                .SelText = " "
            Case acListBox
                .Value = Null
            Case acDate

        End Select
    End With
Next ctl

MsgBox "forms cleared"
End Sub
```

for everything besides a `Date` field that I have. I can't figure out how to reset the date to either 00:00:00:00 or just an empty box. I'd prefer an empty box, but am having trouble finding any information on how to do it. Thanks!

Updated Code:

```
Public Sub clearForms()
Dim frm As Form
Set frm = Forms!Person_Name

Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In frm.Controls
    With ctl
        Select Case .ControlType
            Case acTextBox
                .Value = " "
            Case acCheckBox
                .Value = False
            Case acComboBox
                .SetFocus
                .SelText = " "
            Case acListBox
                .Value = Null
            Case acDate
                .Value = #12:00:00 AM#
        End Select
    End With
Next ctl

MsgBox "forms cleared"
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not applying Null value to date?

Comment: @VanNg the `acDate` doesn't work. it's giving me an undefined variable error no matter what `.Value` i try to give it

Comment: .Value = Null that gives you what type of error?

Comment: @VanNg variable not defined on "acDate"

Comment: Yep. Cause there is no such type - see https://documentation.help/MS-Access-Visual-Basic/acproControlType.htm

Comment: There can be textbox with applied input mask for date and time, or specific ActiveX control as datepicker. Just this check in case condition, maybe

Comment: Just omit this check, delete this case part

Comment: Case acTextBox .Value = Null

Comment: Correct this also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is:

```
Case acDate
    .Value = #00:00:00#
```

But, as noted, there is no "Date" control, thus you can reduce to:

```
For Each ctl In frm.Controls
    With ctl
        Select Case .ControlType
            Case acTextBox, acComboBox, acListBox
                .Value = Null
            Case acCheckBox
                .Value = False
        End Select
    End With
Next ctl
```

Comment: i'm receiving a "variable not defined" error. I'm not sure where i'm going wrong here. I updated my post with the new code

Comment: Who's downvoting this? Those values are the same, but `#00:00:00#` is faster to comprehend for "foreigners" (us outside the US).

Comment: @gustav I receive a "variable not defined" error while using acDate. that is why I downvoted. I was hoping for more guidance on what i'm doing wrong

Comment: But `acDate` comes from your own code. It's not common practice to downvote others for own mistakes.